# "Approximate" metric space as a normed metric spaces

Tags: metric-spaces, euclidean-geometry, normed-spaces

I know that my question is too general, but I am wondering if there exists a way to do Euclid geometry on non-inner-product space metric spaces by view them as a limit of inner product spaces or someting.

I am looking for an example to such method in the "mainstream".

Comment: I don't think this will help you do Euclidean geometry, but it's true that every metric space is isometric to a subspace of some normed vector space.

Comment: Interesting, Thanks. Do you know an application for that to prove even a little non-trivial proposition?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I know any interesting consequences. Maybe there will be some in the references here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski_embedding

Comment: Oh, sorry, it seems that I didn't stated my question well, but the result is still interesting.

Comment: Here is an example that may indicate that what you want isn't possible. Arrange points $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ in a cyclic graph, and say that the distance between two neighbouring points is $1$, and between two non-neighbouring points $2$. Then the metric space $X =\{A, B, C, D\}$ cannot be embedded in any Euclidean space.

Comment: Seems reasonable. Thanks.